# How to add a link using NSMutableAttributedString that is not underlined?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to programmatically add a link to the last part of a UILabel, but not have the entire UILabel become a link (ignore the ranges as I changed the input string).

```
let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a string. This is the link that should be underlined")

mutableString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.website.com", range: NSMakeRange(57, 16))

self.label.attributedText = mutableString
```

The above code does what I want functionally, but now the link is underlined, which is not what I want. So I added the following line:

```
mutableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(57, 16))
```

Now the text in the range won't appear at all. Any ideas as to how to make this work?

Comment: where are you putting this attributed text in one `UILabel` or on `UITextView`?

Comment: I'm putting it on a UILabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

### EDITED

```
    let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a string. This is the link that should be underlined")

    mutableString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.website.com", range: NSMakeRange(0, 16))
    mutableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, 16))
    mutableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.clearColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, 16))
```

[image]

I hope this helps you, for me works like charm

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Despite the name, NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone is actually the default style (with a single underline).

Comment: yeah this only seems to works because the underline is clear color

Comment: If is not clear whats happens? don't work for you? @yash

Comment: Yeah if it's not clear, the underline still shows up even with `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue`. but I don't mind making it clear.. was just expecting it to work with the style alone

Comment: @yash this question is about "How to add a link using NSMutableAttributedString that is not underlined?" what you need to do?

Comment: @Reinier Melian That's exactly what I need to do. Your solution does not remove the underline. Instead, it just changes the underline's color to "clear color". Remove the line that changes its color - the underline will show up. My point is that setting the style to `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue` does not actually remove the underline.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UITextView` instead, which won't add underline on http link.

For example, if you use this html string,

`"<font face=\"Avenir-Heavy\" color=\"#FF0000\">This</font> <shadow>is</shadow> <b>Happy bold, <u>underlined</u>, <stroke width=\"2.0\" color=\"#00FF00\">awesomeness </stroke><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">link</a>!</b> <br/> <i>And some italic on the next line.</i><img src=\"car.png\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" />"`

you will get something as follows; the first uses UILabel, and the second uses UITextView.

[image]